# VoltDB - Renaming a segment?

Tags: segment, voltdb

Are you able to rename a segment in VoltDB?

I have come across a recent issue where a segment has disappeared and below it, it looks like a command to rename the segment, I am very new to voltdb and would like to know if this command is legal?

Comment: What is a segment in regards to VoltDB? What command did you see? Please be more specific.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to me, I have found references to it being possibly down to a Kafta Bug, will follow this bread trail.